# Assigning the reference of one object to a variable does not work in a python script but works in command line

Tags: python, sqlite

This simple script extracts a hierarchy from a table. It's straightforward if you look at the code. Every record has an ID and a parent ID, the script associates in the dictionary `accDictionary` the ID of an account to its path. A "path" is the concatenation of the account names starting from the root.

The script gives this error:

```
longAcctName = curAccount['name'] + '.' + longAcctName;
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The problem is that `curAccount` is not assigned to `a`, but there is a line in the code that should do that.

If I type `curAccount['name']` in the console after the error (I use IDLE editor), I obtain the same result, but if I type `curAccount = a` and then `curAccount['name']`, the behavior is correct, because I see the same name I'd see if I typed `a['name']`, because now `a` and `curAccount` reference to the same object in memory.

Where's the error?

Here is the code:

```
import sqlite3;
conn = sqlite3.connect('export-2014-11-29.sqlite3');
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row;
accCur = conn.cursor();
accNameCur = conn.cursor();
accDictionary = dict();
accounts = accCur.execute('SELECT name, guid, parent_guid FROM accounts');
for a in accounts:
    longAcctName = '';
    curAccount = a;
    while (True):
        longAcctName = curAccount['name'] + '.' + longAcctName;
        if (curAccount['parent_guid'] == ''):
            print 'Questo conto non ha padre.';
            break;
        accNameCur.execute('SELECT name, guid, parent_guid FROM accounts WHERE guid=?', (curAccount['parent_guid'],));
        curAccount = accNameCur.fetchone();
    accDictionary[a['guid']] = longAcctName;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be `curAccount = accNameCur.fetchone();`

You have no check in place for when you've run out of records, so you just keep trying to fetch. The `fetchone` method will return `None` when there's no data remaining to get from the cursor. You should probably change your `while True:` to `while curAccount:` or something of that nature.

Comment: You are right! I thought the error came out at the very first iteration of the loop, instead it's as you say: the first account that gets queried for its parent does not have one!